# Can Windows guest OS work with shared folder on ext hard drive?

Tags: virtualbox, ntfs

I wonder whether I can share a folder via Virtualbox on ext hard drive with Windows guest OS?

Will the speed be similar to shared folder on NTFS hard drive?

Comment: It would help if you put a little more effort into describing your system, such as Ubuntu version, and the method of file sharing you wish to implement.  But if the folder is mounted in your filesystem, you should be able to do a Samba share, and the Windows guest will be able to pick that up.  The speed of access would most likely be limited by the access speed of the external device.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 20.04. By method you mean program? If yes, it is Virtualbox.

Comment: By method I was really asking if there was a specific file sharing mechanism you needed - Samba is one, FTP, SSH, NFS are others.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of the VirtualBox shared folder would be limited by the speed limitation of the physical USB connection between the external hard drive and the computer.